# How to use seprate translation file(en.json) for admin and frontend in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, localization

I am using laravel 6 and need to separate en.json for admin and front end because of some reason

Comment: What do you mean separate `en.json` for admin? By default Laravel uses PHP files to store localization data. Are you trying to convert these files into JSON and send them to the front-end?

Comment: thank for the replay @tamrat  , in my application i want to use 2 translation file for same language 1 for admin end and second for front-end and need both use separately because i have more string and we want manage separately

Comment: Just create a folder inside the lang folder and reference from your template to the correct folder: `trans('admin/your.property')`

Comment: You can have `admin.php` and `public.php` files in your `resources/lang/{locale}` directory. You can put the translations separately in those files and access them using `__('admin.xxx')` or `__('public.xxx')` in your Blade files.

Comment: @tamrat i am using 'Using Translation Strings As Keys' so not using .php in ' Translation Strings As Keys' we use .json file

Comment: @SjoerdLoeve where 'trans('admin/your.property')' this put in blade, what admin, your, and property means

Comment: @Connectify_user sorry, in Blade you will call it @lang('admin/your.property') where your and property are layers of data in your JSON file.

Comment: @SjoerdLoeve i was create lang>admin>en.json and my en.json is contain {
  "areyou" : "Yes you done this.'
} then i call in blade   @lang('admin/en.areyou') output something like admin/en.youare  please help me out.

Comment: @Connectify_user try @lang('admin.areyou') and @ lang('admin/areyou')

Comment: @SjoerdLoeve you try this. because my end its output is 'admin.areyou '

Comment: @Connectify_user I created a test situation and answered your question below.

Answer (score 2):

You better don't use the `Using Translation Strings As Keys` for this purpose. But if you want to.. do the following:

Create in `resources/lang/` a folder named `admin` and put `en.json` in it. Then add in your middleware, controller or whatever you like:

```
Lang::setLocale('admin/en');
```

In your template you can now refer with `@lang('areyou')` to translate.